# Convert a PHP loop to C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, visual-studio, loops

I am trying to convert a page in PHP to C#. The PHP page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Sectors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/default.css">
</head>
<body class="trombinoscope_body">
        <?php
            //MySQL Database Connect
            include 'connect.php';

            $var_sector = $_GET['varsector'];

            $sql    = "SELECT * FROM employees";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql); 

            if($result) {

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                    $rows[] = $row; 
                }
        ?>
    <div class="sector_title">
        <?php echo $var_sector; ?>
    </div>
        <?php
        $level = null; 
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            if ($level != $row['level']) {
                if (isset ($level)) {
                    echo '<br/>';
                } 
                $level = $row['level']; 
            }
        ?>
    <div class="people_box">
        <img class="people_photo" src="photos/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>">
        <div class="name_text">
            <p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></br></p>
        </div>
        <div class="function_text">
            <p style="margin-top: -5px"><?php echo $row['function']; ?></br></p>
        </div> 
        <div class="info_box">
            <img class="line" src="images/line.png">
            <!-- Sector Information -->
            <img class="sector_icon" src="images/sector.png"><p class="info_text"><?php echo $row['sector']; ?></br></p>
            <!-- Location Information -->
            <img class="location_icon" src="images/location.png"><p class="info_text"><?php echo $row['location']; ?></br></p>
            <!-- Mail Information -->
            <img class="mail_icon" src="images/mail.png"><p class="info_text_link"><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row['mail']; ?>"><?php echo $row['mail']; ?></a></br></p>
            <!-- Phone Information -->
            <img class="phone_icon" src="images/phone.png"><p class="info_text"><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></br></p>
            <!-- Skype Information -->
            <img class="skype_icon" src="images/skype.png"><p class="info_text_link"><a href="sip:<?php echo $row['mail']; ?>">Skype for Business</a></br></p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php } } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I already did this (I don't know if it's totally correct, not really the PHP page I know, but that's it.)

**Default.aspx page**

```
<%@ Page 
    Title="Home Page" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="trombinoscope._Default"
%>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="people_box_repeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="people_box">
                <img class="people_photo" src="photos/<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["photo"] %>">
                <!-- Name Information -->
                <div class="name_text">
                    <p><%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["name"] %></br></p>
                </div>
                <!-- Function Information -->
                <div class="function_text">
                    <p style="margin-top: -5px"><%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["function"] %></br></p>
                </div> 
                <div class="info_box">
                    <img class="line" src="images/line.png">
                    <!-- Sector Information -->
                    <img class="sector_icon" src="images/sector.png"><p class="info_text"><%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["sector"] %></br></p>
                    <!-- Location Information -->
                    <img class="location_icon" src="images/location.png"><p class="info_text"><%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["location"] %></br></p>
                    <!-- Mail Information -->
                    <img class="mail_icon" src="images/mail.png"><p class="info_text_link"><a href="mailto:<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["mail"] %>"><%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["mail"] %></a></br></p>
                    <!-- Phone Information -->
                    <img class="phone_icon" src="images/phone.png"><p class="info_text"><%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["phone"] %></br></p>
                    <!-- Skype Information -->
                    <img class="skype_icon" src="images/skype.png"><p class="info_text_link"><a href="sip:<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["mail"] %>">Skype for Business</a></br></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs page**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace trombinoscope
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) => People_box_repeater_method();

        public void People_box_repeater_method()
        {
            using (MySqlConnection mysql_connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter mysql_data_adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM employees", mysql_connection);
                DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
                mysql_data_adapter.Fill(data_table);
                DataView data_view = new DataView(data_table);

                people_box_repeater.DataSource = data_view;
                people_box_repeater.DataBind();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

But I can't convert this part in particular:

```
<?php
$level = null; 
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if ($level != $row['nivel']) {
        if (isset ($level)) {
            echo '<br/>';
        } 
        $level = $row['nivel']; 
    }
?>
```

Basically, this part of the code takes a row from the database in the "level" column and checks if they are equal, if it is the same, the code does nothing, if it is different, the code writes a `</ br>` causing it to break a line.

Nothing I did come close to a result that I can improve. I just need a direction to follow.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (will require understanding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work like this, i put these two lines inside the template:

```
<asp:Label ID="jump_line_label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="retrieve_data_from_aspx" style="display: none;" runat="server" Text='<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["level"] %></asp:Label>
```

And in the code behind I did this:

```
public void People_box_repeater_method()
        {
            mysql_string = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY level ASC";
            mysql_data_adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysql_string, mysql_connection);

            DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
            mysql_data_adapter.Fill(data_table);
            DataView data_view = new DataView(data_table);

            people_box_repeater.DataSource = data_view;
            people_box_repeater.DataBind();

            string jump_line = null;

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in people_box_repeater.Items)
            {
                var retrieve_data_from_aspx = ((Label)item.FindControl("retrieve_data_from_aspx")).Text;
                var jump_line_label = ((Label)item.FindControl("jump_line_label"));

                if (retrieve_data_from_aspx != jump_line)
                {
                    jump_line_label.Text = "</br>";
                }

                jump_line = retrieve_data_from_aspx;

            }    
        }
```

And it worked!